# How do I implement inheritance using iBatis for Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, ibatis

**Please** point me to an example! iBatis documentation doesn't cover this. I have been struggling all morning getting my discriminator and subMap to work!

Answer (score 7):

Interestingly, I just wrote a [tutorial on using Ibatis inheritance](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/06/ibatis-tutorial-inheritance-strategies.html). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Tell me, how is inheritance implemented without the discriminator?